# my ngAnimate doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angularjs-animation

i want to use ngAnimate but somehow it doesn't work and i don't know why.
i have added everything to my page and have injected them in my app but still i am getting nothing.

here is my index and my app;

```js
var app = angular.module('iranfile', ['ngAnimate','ngRoute','mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

```html
<html ng-app="iranfile">
<!-- ye lahze khafe sho-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> home page </title>
 <!-- Add Jquery and bootstrap -->
 <script src="js/jQuery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bs-additional/bootstrap-additions.min.css"/>
 <!-- / Add Jquery and bootstrap -->
 <!-- Angular CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/angular/ng-animation.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular/angular-motion.min.css"/>
 <!-- Angular CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/toastr/toastr.min.css"/>
 <!-- Narvan CSS DOCs -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/singup.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estate.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/favor.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/account.css"/>
 <!-- Narvan CSS DOCs -->
</head>
<body>

</body>
<!-- ADD AngularJs -->
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="css/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/angular/angular-1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-strap/dist/modules/tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-strap/dist/modules/parse-options.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-1.4.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/client-connection.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you actually animating?

Comment: i animating a modal and a aside
but i think angular should use default animation and i do not need to write codes in css for animation ? ha !
cause i add

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/angular/ng-animation.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular/angular-motion.min.css"/>

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is a bit vague. In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into lots of issues when using angular-strap & bootstrap-rtl
Try removing bootstrap rtl and check...

Comment: i try this in simple Example and using bootstrap-rtl but it's worked !

i just don't know why it ain't work here ? ??????????????
as you can see i inject and add every thing i think .